# How do I remove a scanner?

Tags: hp, scanner

I have an HP all-in-one unit with scanner, connected via the network. It has moved around IP addresses in the past due to our DHCP server not giving consistent addresses across resets. (The latter problem has been solved, but too late for the following annoyance.)

I can re-run `hp-setup` to register the new address, but I am left with the old addresses, even after weeks or months:

```
$ scanimage -L
device `hpaio:/net/Officejet_Pro_8600?ip=10.0.0.2' is a Hewlett-Packard Officejet_Pro_8600 all-in-one
device `hpaio:/net/Officejet_Pro_8600?ip=10.0.0.3' is a Hewlett-Packard Officejet_Pro_8600 all-in-one
device `hpaio:/net/Officejet_Pro_8600?ip=10.0.0.4' is a Hewlett-Packard Officejet_Pro_8600 all-in-one
```

(IP addresses changed.)

What's worse, if I actually try to use it within, say, SimpleScan, it can work, but only if I choose the correct scanner between the options of "HP OfficeJet_Pro_8600", "HP OfficeJet_Pro_8600", and "HP OfficeJet_Pro_8600". (The third one works of course; I'm sure it's clear that's the correct one!) These names are all the same despite the fact that I have unique names to the printer and fax in `hp-setup` (which are now duplicated, but I think I'll have better luck removing those extras).

I can't figure out where information about these scanners is stored, or how to clear them, or anything like that. There aren't any other such devices on my subnet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

D'oh, of course I figure it out right after posting.

Anyway, `hp-setup` is still the answer, despite the default GUI only adding things -- run `hp-setup -r` and check everything in the resulting list, even though none appear to be a scanner.

Comment: Since your DHCP  seems to change the printers address all the time .. why don't you set  it up to use a static one? I have a photosmart and its pretty simple to set up a static IP on it.

Comment: (And even if it isn't easy on the printer, most routers will let you set the same IP to be re-assigned to the same MAC address)

Comment: Yeah, it's set that way now, using the behavior Tim mentioned. I didn't set it that way right away because (1) I can't configure the router myself and (2) I didn't want to pick an IP that the router would try to provide another device via DHCP. But I still had the stale IPs present from a while ago.

Comment: On my, pc topday, after upgrading hplip: scanimage -L
device `hpaio:/usb/Officejet_Pro_6830?serial=TH62H811S2' is a Hewlett-Packard Officejet_Pro_6830 all-in-one
device `hpaio:/net/officejet_pro_6830?ip=192.168.1.27&queue=false' is a Hewlett-Packard officejet_pro_6830 all-in-one
Not fixed running hp-setup -r